# CSS + HTML accordian not working in IE 8

Tags: html, css

I want to include accordion drop down into my website and it is not working in IE 8. Here is the code for your reference. I have checked in google and I found out that psuedo elements will not work properly in IE 8 and below. Then what will be the alternative:

```css
 .transition, p, ul li i:before, ul li i:after {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.flipIn, h1, ul li {
  animation: flipdown 0.5s ease both;
}

.no-select, h2 {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 900;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #dce7eb;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
  color: rgba(48, 69, 92, 0.8);
}

body {
  min-height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 90px 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 0 0 #ff6873 inset;
  background-color: #fefffa;
  max-width: 450px;
  padding: 30px;
}
@media (max-width: 550px) {
  body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}

h1, h2 {
  color: #ff6873;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 42px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 34px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fefffa;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  color: rgba(48, 69, 92, 0.8);
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 26px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 800px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  margin-top: 14px;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  perspective: 900;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  border-top: 1px dotted #dce7eb;
}
ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.75s;
}
ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
ul li:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
ul li i {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-6px, 0);
  margin-top: 16px;
  right: 0;
}
ul li i:before, ul li i:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff6873;
  width: 3px;
  height: 9px;
}
ul li i:before {
  transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
ul li i:after {
  transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}
ul li input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}
ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ p {
  margin-top: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 50%);
}
ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ i:before {
  transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ i:after {
  transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}

@keyframes flipdown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotateX(8deg);
  }
  83% {
    transform: rotateX(6deg);
  }
  92% {
    transform: rotateX(-3deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ajax.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>CSS + HTML only Accordion Element</h1>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <i></i>
    <h2>Languages Used</h2>
    <p>This page was written in HTML and CSS. The CSS was compiled from SASS. I used Normalize as my CSS reset and -prefix-free to save myself some headaches. I haven't quite gotten the hang of Slim for compiling into HTML, but someday I'll use it since its syntax compliments that of SASS. Regardless, this could all be done in plain HTML and CSS.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <i></i>
    <h2>How it Works</h2>
    <p>Using the sibling and checked selectors, we can determine the styling of sibling elements based on the checked state of the checkbox input element. One use, as demonstrated here, is an entirely CSS and HTML accordion element. Media queries are used to make the element responsive to different screen sizes.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <i></i>
    <h2>Points of Interest</h2>
    <p>By making the open state default for when :checked isn't detected, we can make this system accessable for browsers that don't recognize :checked. The fallback is simply an open accordion. The accordion can be manipulated with Javascript (if needed) by changing the "checked" property of the input element.</p>
  </li>
</ul>

</body>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: IE 8 is existed .. may i know. why still using IE8?..

Comment: and also transition is not supported in IE 8.. and use this one http://selectivizr.com/ to create support for  in IE6-8.

Comment: use [jQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: Pseudo elements work with no problems at all. `:nth-of-type` and `:last-of-type` will not work. CSS animations will not work. CSS transitions will not work.

Comment: ...also `:checked` is not supported in IE8.